# Can visualforce's RenderAs PDF include href links?

Tags: pdf, salesforce, visualforce

We're using SalesForce's renderAs="PDF" option, and we want a clickable link in the body of the generated PDF. Is this possible?

I have tried an <a href="...">...</a> and I've tried <apex:outputlink value="...">...</apex:outputlink>, both result in a non clickable rendered version.

Has anyone found a way that works in salesforce's engine?

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"  showHeader="false" renderas="pdf">
<apex:outputLink value="https://google.com">https://google.com</apex:outputLink>

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>
...
```

**Update**:
This is browser dependent. Firefox doesn't let you click the link, Google Chrome does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of link are you trying to render in the PDF, a relative link? Using outputlink I have previously had the same behaviour but only for relative links.

Using a full URL should render the hyperlink.

Comment: I've tried 
    [http://www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
That's what I've been testing with.

Comment: This worked perfectly on a simple PDF: `<apex:outputLink value="https://google.com">https://google.com</apex:outputLink>`

Comment: I put it as the 2nd line in my visual force file:
    ... see above

Comment: Ok, you've got the right answer, but it is browser dependent. Firefox doesn't seem to let me click the link, but Google Chrome does. Not exactly what I was hoping for :-) Thanks for you answer though!